# Expand All / Collapse All with tree table not working propery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to apply Expand All/Collapse All functionality to nested tree table but I am getting the desired output. I followed [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554519/jquery-expand-collapse-hierarchical-table-row) for the same. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tron/4SZS4/1/).

```
<a class="myexpand" href="#">Expand</a> | <a class="mycollapse" href="#">Collapse</a>
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <th class="firstCol">Titulo</th>
        <th class="LastCol">Valor</th>
    </thead>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0">
        <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 1</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1">
        <td><span class="toggle"></span>Item 2</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2">
        <td><span class="toggle"></span>Item 3</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="3" class="collapse level3">
        <td>Item x</td>
        <td>Letra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1">
        <td><span class="toggle"></span>Item 4</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2">
        <td>Item 4x</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse collapsable level0">
        <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 5</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse collapsable level1">
        <td>Item 6</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

SCRIPT

---

```
$(function() {
    $('#mytable').on('click', '.toggle', function () {
        //Gets all <tr>'s  of greater depth
        //below element in the table
        var findChildren = function (tr) {
            var depth = tr.data('depth');
            return tr.nextUntil($('tr').filter(function () {
                return $(this).data('depth') <= depth;
            }));
        };

        var el = $(this);
        var tr = el.closest('tr'); //Get <tr> parent of toggle button
        var children = findChildren(tr);

        //Remove already collapsed nodes from children so that we don't
        //make them visible. 
        //(Confused? Remove this code and close Item 2, close Item 1 
        //then open Item 1 again, then you will understand)
        var subnodes = children.filter('.expand');
        subnodes.each(function () {
            var subnode = $(this);
            var subnodeChildren = findChildren(subnode);
            children = children.not(subnodeChildren);
        });

        //Change icon and hide/show children
        if (tr.hasClass('collapse')) {
            tr.removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
            children.hide();
        } else {
            tr.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
            children.show();
        }
        return children;
    });
   $('.toggle').trigger('click');

   $(".myexpand").click(function () {
            $("#mytable tr").show("slow");
   });
    $(".mycollapse").click(function () {
            $("#mytable tr").hide("fast");
   });


});
```

Problem is when I click on **Expand** all tr expands but the image is not expanded and clicked on **Collapse** whole table gets hidden.

Can someone please help me how I do this in efficient way?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: fiddle is already given there...

Comment: I have already provided a fiddle please check link  mysample js in question above.

Answer (score 1):

use  like below.... u r missing tr tag inside thead

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="firstCol">Titulo</th>
            <th class="LastCol">Valor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

and replace your function by my function

```
 $(".mycollapse").click(function () {
            $("#mytable tr").hide("fast");
            $("#mytable thead tr").show("fast");
            $("#mytable tr.level0").show("fast");
        });
```

Comment: Above solution is working fine for collapse,but when I click on expand all the image plus sign is not changed to minus(collapse) sign.

Comment: I tried a logic to manage the expand and collapse images when I click on Expand All link but I am having some problem. @Kundan your solution helped me for collapse,can provide some more information for exapad all.